# How Can i Search a Value in Database If a Column Contains JSON Encode Data in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Hello I want to get the **vendor_service_area** from the following data which is in table basically the data i stored in the details Column With JSON Encoded
[image: Table]

Here is my query:

```
$user_details = DB::table('users_details')->where('user_id',11)->get();
```

Comment: what is your database version ? if you use mysql 8.0 >= check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Comment: I Tried But Failed Can Please Provide Me Query?? @JulienMetral

Comment: `DB::table('users_details')->where('user_id',11)->where('details->profile_data->vendor_service_area', $value)->get();`

Comment: why you used $value Variable @JulienMetral

Comment: your question is to search in a json value in the database so $value is the search

Comment: No, Basically What i Want to do that search User_id and in json Encoded Column Detail I Want to get vendor_service_area value acc to User ID @JulienMetral

Comment: Ok so `DB::table('users_details')->where('user_id',11)->selectRaw('details->profile_data->vendor_service_area as service_area, other_fields')->get();` something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the columns as array in your model. Something like this:

```
class UserDetail extends Model
{
    .
    .
    .
    protected $casts = [
        'details' => 'array',
    ];
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then you can access the `vendor_service_area` with something like this:

```
$user_details->details['profile_details']['vendor_service_area'];
```

Comment: Now I got Error: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.. Any Solution?

Comment: Convert the array into string with json_encode